# Call function with variable array

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function works fine when calling like this.

```
                GenColumns({columns: [
                    { headerText: "ID"},
                    { headerText: "Doc"},
                    { headerText: "Customer ID"}
                ] }]
```

But if I change to this, it doesn’t work.

```
        var col = [{ headerText: " ID", key: "D"},
            { headerText: "Doc"},
            { headerText: "Customer ID"}
        ];

                GenColumns({columns: [
                    col
                ] })
```

How can I call function passing a generated string because “col” variable will be generated and does not type manually?

Thanks
Wilson

Comment: GenColumns({columns: col})

Comment: Change `GenColumns({columns: [col] })` to `GenColumns({columns: col })`. `col` is already an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var col = [{ headerText: " ID", key: "D"},
        { headerText: "Doc"},
        { headerText: "Customer ID"}
    ];

            GenColumns({columns: col})
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
        var col = [{ headerText: " ID", key: "D"},
            { headerText: "Doc"},
            { headerText: "Customer ID"}
        ];

                GenColumns({columns: [
                    col
                ] })
```

Is not the same as first one ... correct replacement is

```
        var col = [{ headerText: " ID", key: "D"},
            { headerText: "Doc"},
            { headerText: "Customer ID"}
        ];

                GenColumns({columns: col })
```

Because you duplicated the arrays. instead of columns : Array( Column ) you made columns : Array( Array( Column ))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
GenColumns({columns: [ col ] })
```

Use

```
GenColumns({columns: col})
```

As `col` is already an array you just need to pass it.